# About system auto delete on old post (more than 3 months ago)

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I like to know what happens if I don't update my question:

[image]

It got deleted automatically and I might not be able to reach it for editing in the future.

I have seen [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) post which was about the system's post auto delete function:

[image: sa]

But that post has existed for 3 months, so would it be deleted by this condition or not?

Comment: Check the timeline view of the post by clicking the clock symbol under the votes bar, and it will tell you which specific criteria applied. Please let us know which one it was.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a `RemoveAbandonedClosed` deletion; the [Help Center](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) says a question is deleted when

> **If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...**
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past 9 days
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. These are "abandoned closed", and are termed as `RemoveAbandonedClosed`.

I'm not 100% sure and you could verify this by checking when the question was closed and when it was deleted by hovering over the "3 months ago" in both banners. With only 9 views it's unlikely to have a positively scoring answer.

It might indeed become hard to find this question as it's not listed on your profile. You can still maintain a reference to it by using the favorites/bookmarks function of your browser.

Even though it is deleted, you can still edit it, since it is not locked. If you think you improved it sufficiently enough to be warranted for reopening and undeletion, you can flag the post for ♦ moderator attention, asking to reopen and undelete it.